# Выборка некоторого количества данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы: таблица `platform` с полями `user_id, id_platform` и таблица `setting` с полями `user_id(связь с таблицей platform), sound, animation, private`.

Я получаю данные "id_platform" (их может быть несколько) через GET. Как мне сделать запрос, чтобы выбрать все поля private у переданных пользователей?
Составила такой запрос:

```
$insert ="SELECT `user_id`,`private` FROM `platform`,`setting` WHERE `platform`.`id_platform` IN (".$list.") AND `setting`.`user_id`";
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно?

Comment: ну вы чуть чуть не дописали ... `and platform.user_id=setting.user_id`

Comment: @Mike это нужно добавить в самый конец я вас правильно поняла?

Comment: Ну setting.user_id у вас там уже зачем то написан, значит к нему дописать `=platform.user_id` вообще не помешало бы на какой нибудь http://sql-ex.ru и хоть немного разобраться в sql, базовые знания за день приобретаются

Comment: @Mike я обязательно воспользуюсь вашим советом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insert ="SELECT `platform`.`user_id`,`setting`.`private` FROM `platform` INNER JOIN `setting` ON `platform`.`user_id` = `setting`.`user_id` WHERE `platform`.`id_platform` IN (".$list.")";
```

Comment: Я может очень глупая но мне не понятно что там в "и так далее".

Comment: @user206425 условие where. Щас поправлю тогда.

Comment: Спасибо больше.